can't locate node.js error making express site
I'm building a portfolio site with express and i'm trying to make a dashboard to add my works from the interface but i get some errors when i try to upload files. the ejs form is encoded in multipart/form-data
//this is how multer is set up
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {

      const workPath = `./data/works/${req.body.id}/`
  
      fs.access(workPath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          // La directory non esiste la crea
          fs.mkdirSync(workPath, { recursive: true })
        }

        cb(null, workPath)
      })
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

this is the post request causing the error (i guess)
it's made to add those three files in a folder and add data and their name to a json
router.post('/addwork', auth,

  upload.fields([
    { name: 'image', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'audio', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'file', maxCount: 1 }
  ]), 
  
  (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body)
    //console.log(req.files)
    console.log(validationResult(req))

    var newWorkInfo = req.body
    
    for (const key in req.files) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(req.files, key)) {
        const filename = req.files[key][0].filename
        const field = req.files[key][0].fieldname
        //console.log(`${filename}, ${field}`)       
        newWorkInfo[field] = filename
      }
    }
    
    //console.log(newWorkInfo)
    const worksDbPath = "./data/works.db.json"
    let worksData = [];
    try {
      worksData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(worksDbPath, 'utf8'));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    worksData.unshift(newWorkInfo)

    fs.writeFileSync(worksDbPath, JSON.stringify(worksData, null, 2))

    req.flash("authenticated", true)
    res.redirect("/admin/dashboard")
  })

this is the error i get when i try to submit the form
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile  at ...\PortfolioSite\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:442:11

the script worked for some tasks, then started to not work anymore for some reason...

in the error stack, what's the line below the one you are showing? it should point to the line in your code where it throws.. and it should have something to do with res.sendFile, are you using it somewhere, include that code
